# iOS application that self-updates javascript (or other interpreted) resources?

Tags: javascript, ios, appstore-approval

Based on several questions I've seen:

- [How to implement auto-updating iOS Apps from App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069602/how-to-implement-auto-updating-ios-apps-from-app-store)
- [auto upgrading iOS apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884419/auto-upgrading-ios-apps)
- [Is it possible to have a self-updating iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977265/is-it-possible-to-have-a-self-updating-iphone-application)

it seems pretty clear that apps are not allowed to "self-update" code on startup (or through some other mechanism within the app), since the new code was part of the app submitted to app store.

However, there are plenty of applications out there that do perform automatic updates on startup (for example, [this popular game](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/the-simpsons-tapped-out/id497595276?mt=8) downloads several hundred MB on first startup) - it seems this type of thing is allowed for resources - as long as the download is data/resources - stuff that doesn't change the compiled code.

Technically, Javascript included with an app's resource bundle could be considered a resource, and so it's safe to auto-update any included Javascript.  On the other hand, Javascript could be considered 'code', as it's interpreted by Webkit (in a `UIWebView`) and executed.  If this counts as code, one could even go to the extreme and create some interpreter that runs commands included in the app based on contents of an xml file (very easily considered a resource) that gets auto-updated to the app. Would this count as 'code'?

**So, my main questions I'm looking for answers to**:

- **Where exactly is the line between 'resource' and 'code'? Does 'code' just mean 'compiled Objective-C'?**
- **Are there any known examples of accepted apps that do something like this?**

Also, since I'm sure it'll be asked, my main reason for wanting to download and execute the javascript locally instead of just hitting the remote site all the time is for performance / offline capabilities.